# Usage guidance revision histories show formatting, which doesn't work in them

Tags: bug, markdown, revisions-list, tag-wiki-excerpt

[This](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/3615/revisions) excerpt history shows up with italics. But no formatting at all will ever show up in a tag's excerpt, so it seems pretty silly to have it show that way (i.e., wrong, and possibly misleading to newbie editors) in the history.